# n divs with the same name in n forms with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to display the content of the field: "nombrePlato"
in the div: `<div id = 'carrito'>`, but there is a problem as there are n "carrito" divs. And it only shows me the field in the first div. How can I display the content of the field in the div that is in its corresponding form?

menus.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $restaurante=$_GET['restaurante'];
    chdir(getcwd()."/".$restaurante);
    $id_fichero= @fopen("menus.txt","r") or die("<B>El fichero no se pudo abrir");
    ?>
    <?php
        $j=0;
        while (!feof($id_fichero))
        {            
        if(($linea=trim(fgets($id_fichero,256),"\n\r"))!=false) 
        {
            echo("<button type='button' class='accordion'>".$linea."</button>");                
            echo("<div class='panel'>");
            $id_fichero2= @fopen($linea.".txt","r") or die("<B>El fichero no se pudo abrir");
            while (!feof($id_fichero2))
            {
                echo("<form method='post' id='platos'>");
                if(($linea2=trim(fgets($id_fichero2,256),"\n\r"))!=false)
                {
                    echo("<button type='button' id='plato' name='plato' class='plato'>".$linea2."</button><br>");
                    echo("<input type='hidden' id='nombrePlato' name='nombrePlato' value='".$linea2."'>");                    
                    echo("<div id='carrito'>");
                    echo("</div>");
                }
                echo("</form>"); 
            }
            echo ("</div>");
        }
        $j++;
        }            
    ?>
<script src="collapsible.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

anadirCarrito.php

```
<?php
$nombrePlato=$_POST["nombrePlato"];
echo($nombrePlato);
?>
```

ajax.js

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){    
    $('.plato').click(function(){
    var url = "anadirCarrito.php";
    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,   
       data: $(this).closest("form").serialize(), 
       success: function(data)             
       { 
         $('#carrito').html(data);  
       }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: there are n "carrito" divs - what do you meant by this statement. there are more than one div with id "carrito"? If yes then your html design is wrong and needs to be fixed. Identifier should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In valid html, you cannot have multiple elements with the same id. Only first one will be recognized in that case. Instead give a class or unique id to div and use that.

```
echo("<div class='carrito'>");
echo("</div>");
```

and populate that in js

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){    
    $('.plato').click(function(){
    var url = "anadirCarrito.php";
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,   
       data: $form.serialize(), 
       success: function(data)             
       { 
         $form.find('.carrito').html(data);  
       }
       });
    });
});
```

You should also consider giving unique ids to form, button and any other elements generated dynamically within loop to avoid such issues.